# jQuery load external files into static popup dynamically

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, popup, load, external

I'm getting trouble by opening a popup in combination with loading of an external file. The first two times it works great. At the third time i get a "File not Found" error even though the file is available. (It's a Mobile WebApp and i try it on Safari / jQueryMobile).

Here comes my code:

```
$(document).on("pageinit", '#pageContainer', function() {
 $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
     $("a", "#list").click(function (event, ui) {
      var attr = $(this).attr('id');
  var name = attr.replace ('linkID','');
      $("#singleSwipe_popup").load('dynamic/' + name + '.html', function() {
   $(".singlePopup" ).on({
        popupbeforeposition: function() {
    // init Swipe-Slider ... on global var singleSwipeSlider ... Works ...
    }, popupafterclose: function() {
     delete singleSwipeSlider;  // destroy the swipe slider
     $('#singleSwipe_popup').empty();  // clean popup content
       }
   });
  });
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="prodPopupsConainter">
 <div data-role="popup" class="singlePopup ui-corner-none" id="popupSingle" data-overlay-theme="b">
 <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="a" data-icon="delete"     data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Close</a>
 <div id="singleswipe-left" class="swipe-left"></div>
 <div class="wrapAndFloat" id="singleSwipe_popup">
 <!-- POPUP content comes here -->
</div>
 <div id="singleswipe-right" class="swipe-right"></div>
</div>          
</div>
```

....
Without the html code of the popup and "`$("#prodPopupsConainter").load ...`" the dynamically loading works great.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved with an update of jQuery 1.9.1, jQueryMobile 1.3.1 and Phonegap to Version 2.8.0.